# Am trying to write a program that ask for input and insert it to an array keeping increase order using pointers in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I wrote this code that sort the giving element while inserting then ask for an element and insert it while kipping an ascending order

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int i, j, n, * p, v;
  printf("\n Entrer la taille du tableau:");
  scanf("%d", & n);
  p = (int * ) malloc(n * sizeof(int));

  printf("Enter l\'élément(s) 1:");
  scanf("%d", p);

  for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    /*the condition for the input*/

    do {
      printf("Enter l\'élément(s) %d:", i + 1);
      scanf("%d", (p + i));
    }
    while (p[i] < p[i - 1]);
  }
  printf("\n Affichage du tableau\n");
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%d ", *(p + i));
  }

  /*INTEGRATE A VALUE IN THE ARRAY 'tab'*/
  printf("\n Entrer la valeur de v: ");
  /*scanf("%d", p);
  printf("\n Insertion de v=%d dans le tableau\n", *p);*/

  for (int * current = p; current != p + 1; ++current)

  {
    int value;
    scanf("%d", & value);

    int * pos = current;
    for (; pos != p && value < * (pos - 1); --pos) {
      * pos = * (pos - 1);
    }

    * pos = value;
  }

  for (int * current = p; current != p + n; ++current) {
    printf("%d ", * current);
  }
  putchar( '\n' );

  free(p);
  return 0;
}
```

what i get is that if i entred a list like ---3 5 7 8--- when i insert a numbre like 4 i get ---4 5 7 8--- how to make it display ---3 4 5 7 8---

Comment: @oka first element we entered before the while loop

Comment: Oh, I missed that, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following only iterates once:

```
for (int * current = p; current != p + 1; ++current)
```

If `current` is `p`, then `current + 1 == p + 1`, and `++current` increments `current` to `current + 1` after the first iteration.

This loop never runs:

```
int * pos = current;
for (; pos != p && value < * (pos - 1); --pos)
```

If `current` is `p`, and `pos` is `current`, then `pos` is `p`.

So the value is always assigned to the first element of `p`.

```
*pos = value;
```

---

To insert a value to an already sorted (ascending) array, you need to find the position at which the element is greater than the given value, and move it and all successive elements ahead (towards the *end* of the array) by one. Then assign the new value to the position found.

If you never find an element greater than the value provided, you assign it to the end of the array.

Here is an example of inserting a *single* element into an array. Note we initially allocate space for one additional `int`. If you wanted to repeatedly insert elements in a loop, you will need to [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) the array as you go, to make room for more elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int get_int(void)
{
    int x;

    if (1 != scanf("%d", &x))
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    return x;
}

void print_array(int *a, int len)
{
    printf("Contents of the array: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter the size of the array: ");

    int n = get_int();

    if (n < 1)                
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    int *p = malloc((1 + n) * sizeof *p);

    printf("Enter the first element: ");
    *p = get_int();

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        do {
            printf("Enter element #%d: ", i + 1);
            p[i] = get_int();
        } while (p[i] < p[i - 1]);
    }

    print_array(p, n);

    printf("Enter a value to insert: ");
    int v = get_int();
    int inserted = 0;

    for (int i = 0; !inserted && i < n; i++) {
        if (p[i] > v) {
            int l = n;

            while (l > i) {
                p[l] = p[l - 1];
                l--;
            }

            p[i] = v;
            inserted = 1;
        }
    }

    if (!inserted)
        p[n] = v;

    print_array(p, n + 1);
    free(p);
}
```

Using this program:

```
Enter the size of the array: 5 
Enter the first element: 11
Enter element #2: 22
Enter element #3: 33
Enter element #4: 44
Enter element #5: 55
Contents of the array: 
11 22 33 44 55 
Enter a value to insert: 40
Contents of the array: 
11 22 33 40 44 55
```